# Why does a type "Date" attribute in CoreData turns out to be type "TimeInterval" in the entity class extension?

Tags: swift, core-data

I created an entity that has two attributes of type 'date'.

[image]

However, when I try to set these attributes, Xcode complains that these are "TimeInterval":

```
func updateUI() {
    titleTextView.text = entry?.title!
    textTextView.text = entry?.text!
    if let date = entry?.dueDate {
        dateInput.text = formatter(date) //err: Cannot convert value of type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double') to expected argument type 'Date'
    }
    let type32: Int32 = entry!.type
    let type: Int = Int(type32)
    priorityInput.text = priorityOptions[type]
}
```

[image]

The extension, I chose "category/extension" for this entity, that Xcode generated is not editable:

```
extension Entry {

    @nonobjc public class func fetchRequest() -> NSFetchRequest<Entry> {
        return NSFetchRequest<Entry>(entityName: "Entry")
    }

    @NSManaged public var creatTime: TimeInterval. //this one and the "dueDate"
    @NSManaged public var dueDate: TimeInterval
    @NSManaged public var ifDone: Bool
    @NSManaged public var text: String?
    @NSManaged public var title: String?
    @NSManaged public var type: Int32

}
```

[image]

Why is this happening and how can I turn these two into the date?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `TimeInterval` will be the number of seconds since 2001-01-01T00:00:00Z. Xcode generates the property with this type because you have checked the "Use Scalar Type" checkbox in the first screenshot.

You can create a `Date` from these `TimeInterval`s like this:

```
Date(timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate: someTimeInterval)
```

You should uncheck it, and regenerate the classes. The types will now be `NSDate`.

However, if you want the Swift `Date` types, you need another solution. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39778111/use-swifts-date-with-coredata).

Comment: that totally fixed it! Thanks!

Comment: Actually Core Data stores a date as the time interval since the reference date Jan 1, 2001, compare https://stackoverflow.com/a/33605000/1187415.

Comment: @MartinR I totally thought they would use the same epoch as everyone else... Fixed.